# Rogue Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

It happens sometimes when I open the chrome browser, some rogue extension would open a website (ad) by itself.

How do I know which chrome extension did this action?
Knowingly, the devtools don't have logs since I just opened the browser.

Comment: Leave the devtools open and reload the page?

Comment: @DavidPostill Issue won't happen if chrome running in background/tray.

Answer (score 2):

One way to debug it is to launch Chrome with `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` switch:

1. Create/copy a shortcut to `chrome.exe`, usually located in `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`
2. <kbd>RMB</kbd> on that shortcut -> choose <kbd>Properties</kbd>
3. Add `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` at the end of target.
4. Check dev tools, especially `Console` and `Network` tabs for any suspicious activity. Use the `Initiator` field to help you.

Note that this will only work if you don't have Chrome already opened.

Answer (score 1):

The brute-force method for finding which extension is doing this
is to disable extensions until this behavior stops.

Once you find the extension, you may either remove it or disable ads
in its preferences (if there is such an option).

Comment: Yes, binary search is a reasonable option. The extension is randomly throwing this ad, further complicating the search.