# Chrome HAR logs - does collection only start when the Network tab is opened?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

We're troubleshooting something that needs the Chrome HAR log collected.  Just to confirm the timing, it appears that we have to press <kbd>F12</kbd> and switch to the `Network` tab BEFORE we do anything of importance.

Is everything from before switching to the `Network` tab lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the recording in the Developer Tools, Network tab.
Before doing that, nothing is recorded.

Unfortunately, you cannot close the Tools while recording,
as closing and opening will have the effect of clearing
any accumulated information in the Network panel.

You may resize the Tools so as to minimize the screen space they take.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the dev tools open with `Network` tab active automatically. Follow these steps:

- press cog icon (settings) in dev tools menu bar -> `Preferences` -> enable `Record network log` setting - this gets rid of the requirement of switching to `Network` tab
  [image: Setting]
- launch Chrome with `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` CLI switch (when no other Chrome window is opened), more details in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1777064/1145698) - this  presses <kbd>F12</kbd> automatically for you

This way, every tab will launch with all the requests recorded - basically a sort of debugging mode. This should work in any Chromium-based browser BTW.